# Regarding time out in code

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

```
  for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
    long long int n;
 //taking the input limit
    cin >> n;
    long long int  n1=8,n2=34,sum=10;
    //iteration till the limit
    while(n2<=n)
    {
        long long int l=n2;
      //for finding the next even fibonacci number
        n2=4*(n2)+n1;
        n1=l;
        sum+=n1;
    }
    cout<<sum<<endl;
}
```

This is the code for finding the sum of even fibonacci numbers given a limit n.
There is a time out problem when I used int in place of long long int. Is there a difference in processing different data types?How  will there  be a change in performance?

Comment: You overflow with `int` most likely, thus never breaking out of the loop.

Comment: Please provide your test values for `n`

Comment: Can you explain??What happens when there is overflow?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make n2=34.
We can use array to finish this question, like this:

```
int a[1001];
memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
while(!EOF){
    a[0]=a[1]=1;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
        a[i]=a[i-1]+a[i-2];
    }
    cout<<a[n];
}
```

Comment: I just need even fibonacci numbers.So i have derived this formula.It might be creating storage problem in case if n value is very large.So i haven't used arrays.